# How do i fail a task in Ansible if the variable contains a boolean value? I want to perform input validation for Ansible playbooks

Tags: ansible, jinja2

The variables are being passed as extra_args by loading them from a YAML file.
I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
- name: Check if variable are of type boolean
  fail:
    msg: "Variable '{{ item }}' is not a boolean"
  when: item is not bool
  with_items: "{{ required_boolean_vars }}"
```

Also, similar to boolean, how could I do the same for integer, dictionary and object type.

Comment: What is "object" type?

Answer (score 4):

There is a general [`type_debug` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#debugging-filters) which returns the type, so for Boolean the condition is:

```
when: "item | type_debug == 'bool'"`
```

Another way:

```
when: item is sameas true or item is sameas false
```

For a dictionary:

```
when: item is mapping
```

For a list:

```
when: item is iterable
```

---

<sup>Also, the above conditional checks `item` for being Boolean as you asked in the title. Add `not` if you wanted to test for the opposite as your code suggests...</sup>

Comment: Interesting that you can test when an item is not string, but not when an item is not bool...

Comment: I tested bool, boolean, Boolean... none of them valid. This works. Thanks @techraf, good job.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found to fail task if variables NOT of type boolean was

```
- name: Check if variable are of type boolean
  assert:
    that: "{{ item }} == false or {{ item }} == true"
    msg: "Variable {{ item }} is not of type boolean"
  with_items: "{{ required_boolean_vars }}"
```

where required_boolean_vars contains a list of variables I want to check.

Comment: `that:` is a Jinja2 expressions itself, don't use curly brackets inside.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to ensure a variable is not a boolean, is to use the sameas Jinja2 test like this:

```
when: item is not sameas true and item is not sameas false
```